# Excel - populate pivottable axis dates for trendline

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, pivot-chart

I have the following pivot table, showing products in the following level of details (LOD)

```
1- Year
2- name
3- type
```

The following picture shows them at LOD 1:
[image: Pivot chart of two lines with linear and logarithmic trendline]

I want the chart to populate the missing years at LOD 1, so the trendline can be used to forecast.

1- Is it necessary, does the trendline already take the year into consideration when forecasting?

2- How can I add the missing years, assuming I have a Date cell per row?